# How do I make optional text box tags part of the flow of the signing experience?

Tags: docusignapi

My company has built an adapter for Docusign in C#. I'm adjusting this adapter to add more {TEXTBOX} tags that do not duplicate.

The customer wants these optional text boxes to be part of the steps in the signing experience. IE: When I click "Next" as the signer, it will step me through the optional tags.

We are using XML in the adapter rather than JSON.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your questions. THANK YOU.

Comment: Thanks, Larry! I always do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set the `tabOrder` attribute for the fields (tabs).

PS, why are you using XML instead of JSON?

PPS, if tabOrder doesn't work, it could be that the feature switch is not turned on for your account. If this is the case, contact DocuSign support and ask them to enable the feature. See this [report](https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000069k6PvSAI/change-tab-order-of-fields-in-template).

Comment: Do I have to do that for every tab we've adapted to set their order, or just inside the tabgroup? 

IE... we have TEXTBOX1, TEXTBOX2, etc. They are in a textTab group. We also have TITLE1, TITLE2, etc. 

If I set tab order on the TEXTBOX1 and 2, will that only apply to the tabs within the textTab group, or do I need to set tab order globally across all the tabs in all the groups? I'm assuming just locally to the tab I care about?

TL;DR: Essentially, you're saying if I set tabOrder at all, and confirm the setting is on in the account, it should make these tabs part of the flow, right?

Comment: PS. I don't know. I just work here.

PPS. Thanks very much for this! I couldn't find that to save my life, so maybe this SO will be useful for people down the line!

Comment: What we're looking for is the Admin page, actually, Larry. 
https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-auto-navigate-or-skip-past-optional-fields-such-as-check-boxes-or-radio-buttons#options

The auto-navigation in Docusign has an option to "Navigate All Fields" which will accomplish what we want. In our case, the customer needs to configure this.

Thanks for your help! It definitely got me where I needed to go!